# C++11: unique_ptr complains about incomplete type, but not when I wrap it

Tags: c++

There are already a good number of questions about unique_ptr and incomplete type on SO, but none can give me a concept in understanding why the following does not work:

```
// error: ... std::pair<...>::second has incomplete type
template<typename K, typename T> struct Impl {
    typedef typename std::unordered_map<K,Impl<K,T>>::iterator iter_type;
    std::unique_ptr<iter_type> ptr;
    Impl() : ptr(new iter_type()) {}
};

int main() { Impl<int,int>(); return 0; }
```

while the following does:

```
template<typename K, typename T> struct Impl {
  struct Wrapper {
    typedef typename std::unordered_map<K,Impl<K,T>>::iterator iter_type;
    iter_type iter;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> ptr;
  Impl() : ptr(new Wrapper()) {}
};

int main() { Impl<int,int>(); return 0; }
```

I don't see where the technical difference is: If `std::pair<...>::second` (that is, `Impl<K,T>`) was incomplete to `Impl` in the first example, it should be incomplete to `Wrapper` in the second one as well. Also,
when it suffices to wrap the `unique_ptr` in a struct, why is there a restriction for the first case?

**UPDATE**:

After Dietmar Kühl's answer, I think the problem can be reduced to the following:

```
template<typename K, typename T> struct Impl {
    typename std::unordered_map<K,Impl<K,T>>::iterator ptr;
};
```

vs

```
template<typename K, typename T> struct Impl {
    struct Wrapper {
        typename std::unordered_map<K,Impl<K,T>>::iterator iter;
    };
    Wrapper *ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the first case the incomplete type is used with the `std::unordered_map<K, Impl<K, T>`: To determine what `iterator` is, parts of `std::unordered_map<K, Impl<K, T>` need to be instantiated at a time when `Impl` is merely declared. The `std::unique_ptr<...>` has not thing to do with error. You can remove the use of `iter_type` as the `typedef` needs to verify that it is a type.

On the other hand, when wrapping the use of the iterator type into `Wrapper`, this nested type isn't used prior to the constructor implementation. Of course, inline defined functions behave as if the class was just fully defined and they are implemented just outside the class definition, i.e., the above code is equivalent to

```
template<typename K, typename T> struct Impl {
  struct Wrapper {
    typedef typename std::unordered_map<K,Impl<K,T>>::iterator iter_type;
    iter_type iter;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> ptr;
  Impl();
};
template<typename K, typename T>
Impl<K, T>::Impl() : ptr(new Impl<K, T>::Wrapper()) {}
```

That is, when the definition of `Wrapper` is needed and instantiated, `Impl` is defined.

Comment: Do you mean that the difference is that the `Wrapper` constructor is not compiled before the `Impl` class is **considered** fully implemented? So the Wrapper is just making the construction of the whole thing a two-step process artificially when effectively the compilation order might be exactly the same?

Comment: @JoSo: Members of class templates are instantiated when used. `Wrapper` is a member of a class template and it is only used in the definition of the constructor. The `typedef` isn't really a member and to define the class template `Impl` it is sort of instantiated. So, yes, making it a two stage process avoid the problem of the type not, yet, being defined.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to tell the compiler "yes, this type really exists!"?. I mean, I can also say `struct NewType; NewType *ptr;` inside the class without ever defining NewType and it works! Is this only a weakness in the spec / implementation or are there deeper reasons behind it?

Comment: @JoSo: You ask the `std::unordered_map<K, Impl<K, T>>` whether it has a nested type. The implementation of this class template seems to feel that you need to ask this question only if the value type is complete. Since template arguments to any of the class templates in the standard library need to be complete unless specified others (see 17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions] paragraph 2, last bullet), the implementation is entirely entitled to do so.

Comment: Completing to make it more obvious: by "nested type" you mean the `::iterator`. Thank you for taking the time, you've been a great help.